# How to collapse two rows into one?

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

What my table looks like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| type |   button_name    |    primary    |    secondary    |    type_name    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      name1_1     |       23      |       0         |    type1_name   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      name1_2     |       0       |       50        |    type1_name   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      name1_3     |       27      |       0         |    type2_name   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |      name1_4     |       0       |       8         |    type2_name   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |      name2_1     |       78      |       0         |    type3_name   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |      name2_2     |       0       |       29        |    type3_name   |
```

What I want it to look like:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| type |   first    |    secondary    |    primary    |    secondary    |    type_name    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   name1_1  |      name1_2    |       23      |       50        |    type1_name   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   name1_3  |      name1_4    |       27      |       8         |    type2_name   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |   name2_1  |      name2_2    |       78      |       29        |    type3_name   |
```

Basically, I have data on whether or not a user clicks the primary or secondary button for a popup, but I'm having trouble getting the data from the same popup to be in one row.

Let me know if any other info is needed.

Thanks,

Comment: Are those `0` values actually zero, or rather, null?

Comment: First you should not have added specific column for clicks for each type of button (`primary`, `secondary`) if the objective is to collect clicks to a button... just `numberClicks` and the `type` (primary / secondary) would be better instead of relying on the button name and the specific column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `nvl` (for case when primary on secondary is missing)

```sql
SELECT
    nvl (t1.type, t2.type) type t1.button_name first,
    t2.button_name secondary,
    t1.primary,
    t2.secondary,
    nvl (t1.type_name, t2.type_name) type_name
from
    my_table t1
    full outer join my_table t2 on (
        t1.type = t2.type
        and t1.type_name = t2.type_name
        and t2.secondary > 0
        and t1.primary > 0
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The column names you chose are not great (type, primary, and then secondary listed twice). While they may be fine in Databricks, they can cause trouble in other DBMS. I would consider adjusting those.

You could use a `CTE` such as this. Adjust if those are null vs 0 values. If there are cases without a "secondary", then change to LEFT join.

```
create table table1 (
  type integer, 
  button_name varchar(20), 
  t_primary integer, 
  t_secondary integer, 
  type_name varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into table1 values 

(1, 'name1_1', 23, 0, 'type1_name'),
(1, 'name1_2', 0, 50, 'type1_name'),
(1, 'name1_3', 27, 0, 'type2_name'),
(1, 'name1_4', 0, 8, 'type2_name'),
(2, 'name2_1', 78, 0, 'type3_name'),
(2, 'name2_2', 0, 29, 'type3_name');
```

---

```
with secondary as (
  select type, button_name, t_secondary, type_name
  from table1
  where t_secondary > 0
  )
select t.type, 
  t.button_name as first, 
  s.button_name as second, 
  t.t_primary, s.t_secondary, 
  t.type_name
from table1 t
join secondary s
  on t.type = s.type
 and t.type_name = s.type_name
where t.t_primary > 0;
```

| type | first | second | t_primary | t_secondary | type_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1_1 | name1_2 | 23 | 50 | type1_name |
| 1 | name1_3 | name1_4 | 27 | 8 | type2_name |
| 2 | name2_1 | name2_2 | 78 | 29 | type3_name |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `max()`, and to get first and secondary button you can use `group_concat()` then `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to splite the concatenated column into two columns :

```
with cte as (
  select max(type) as type, group_concat(button_name) as button_name, max(primary_) as primary_, max(secondary) as secondary_, type_name
  from mytable
  group by type_name
)
select  type, SUBSTRING_INDEX(button_name, ',', 1) AS first, SUBSTRING_INDEX(button_name, ',', -1) AS secondary, primary_ , secondary_, type_name
from cte;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2ewtybEu)

Comment: Unfortunately, group_concat doesn't work in Databricks (to my knowledge).